# Could an organization with no peer joining a channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Assuming no access rights limitations, could an organization without owning any peer join a channel?

Answer (score 2):

A channel is created between Orgs, peers don't come into play yet. An Org can also join a channel at a later point. Have a look here for more details : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html

Once that process is completed, an Org can add peers to the channel it joined. At this point it can have some meaningful participation, meaning each peer will have its own database and its own chaincode, chaincode containers, versions etc. Of course, an Org won't be able to interact with the channel until peers are added.

So yes, an Org can be part of a channel without any peers, but it won't have any meaningful part until peers are added.

Comment: "Org won't be able to interact with the channel until peers are added", does it mean the org which has no added peer couldn't even send a transaction proposal?

Answer (score 1):

Only peers can join to the channel. The Org without peers has the permission to join later, but he will not have access to the network, that mean he dont have a copy of the ledger or state of the blockchain and without peer cannot make transactions. When the org join a peer to the channel, the peer will download the blockchain and keep updated the ledger.

Comment: Does it mean the org which has no peer couldn't even send a transaction proposal? Thanks

Comment: In a production environment the org will need a Peer to endorse the transaction, so its important for the org to have a peer to make the transaction.

Comment: And yes, the org can make the transaction from client side (without peers in the channel), but make sure that he's out from the chaincode policy endorsement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is very common to have an organization that only has clients in it, and has a separate CA and different MSP ID.

Answer (score 0):

In the configtx.yaml, a channel includes an organization, but the organization has no peer joining the channel. The idengtity of the organization could send a transaction proposal successfully.